# Minification of Dynamic Javascript using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, minify, inline-code

I have some JavaScript, which is generated by PHP code, using a template.

The result of the template is a file contain JavaScript but with  statements scattered through out it.

I want to reduce the size of this file by removing white space and comments.

However all I can find on the web are tools for plain JavaScript, which are extremely complex.

I have all ready write a script to reduce HTML, and CSS based content using the same system, I'm looking for info on reducing the size of JavaScript file so I can write a reduction script that can handle the PHP code being in the file.

So what I want is:

A tutorial for reducing the size of JavaScript code.
A simple to follow script for reducing JavaScript size I can analysis.
Or a Tool that works fine with PHP inline with the JavaScript Code (Must be either Public Domain, or Open Source allowing for use in commercial works)

EDIT:

```
$script = preg_replace('%/\*.*?\*/%','',$script);
$compress = preg_split('%("|\'|/)(?:\\\\|\\\1|[^\1])*?\1|<\?php\s+(?:("|\')(?:\\\\|\\\2|[^\2])*?\2|[^"\']*?)*?\?>%',$script);
preg_match_all('%(("|\'|/)(?:\\\\|\\\2|[^\2])*?\2|<\?php\s+(?:("|\')(?:\\\\|\\\3|[^\3])*?\3|[^"\']*?)*?\?>)%',$script,$no_compress);
foreach ($compress as &$block) { $block = preg_replace('%\s+%',' ',$block); }
```

I think I've solved it, the above should remove C-style comments, then split the remaining code around PHP blocks, Javascript Strings ' or ", and Regex Patterns /, and also extract the code blocks, strings, and Regex Patterns, Code inside a Pattern or String should be ignored as its second the Option in Regex.
The Final line should reduce the white space in the compress blocks to a single space

Then It should just be a matter of recombination of the blocks, i.e.

```
$cscript .= $compress[$i].$no_compress[$i]
```

To rebuild the script.

Any thing I've missed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: hey! it is awesome. Just a question. can i use it on production server? i mean it will not create any issue or vulnerability

Comment: Also i  want to implement it in Zend. What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

By dynamic javascript you mean javascript that has PHP tags scattered through it? If thats the case then you REALLY ought to find new programming methods Like a JSON stream. I have also used payloads in my sites and that might be a method you'd conciser other than PHP JS. You might be able to use a generic PHP and JS Minifier to make the PHP page smaller. Good luck.